# Proving conditions on connected sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

Consider a metric space $(X, d)$ and two connected sets $A_1, A_2 ⊂ X$. How to:

- (a) Show that $A_1 ∩ A_2$ is not necessarily connected.
- (b) Show that
  $A_1 ∪ A_2$ is not necessarily connected

  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I recommend trying it out by just drawing some shapes on paper that overlap each other in different ways.

Comment: Try finding counterexamples in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb R^2$. Drawing out the sets may help.

Answer (score 1):

HINTS:

$$\between$$

$$\bullet\quad\bullet$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

(a) Consider intersecting an annulus by a small and narrow rectangle in the plane.

Can you construct a similar one for (b)?